# SVN suggest me to merge also the revision which are merge themself

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I'm **merging** from the **RTM** branch to the **Main** branch, I would expect that SVN would NOT suggest me to merge the revision which I merged from Main to RTM.

It seems to obvious to me..

I merge revision 1 from M to R, it creates the revision 2 (in R)

Then I try to merge from R to M, obviously I don't want to merge revision 2 (which is already in M)

How can I solve?

[image]

I'm merging from the RTM branch to the Main branch.

Answer (score 2):

> Then I try to merge from R to M, obviously I don't want to merge revision 2 (which is already in M)

But you *have*, because merge in SVN doesn't use any assumptions and|or collected history, only list of merged|not-merged from SRC to DST revisions

Comment: But so.. which is the best practice? I cannot merge again.. I would get an error..